# bought a siamese kitten who was using her litter boxes,but when i changed my bedding she started peeing and pooping on my bed

Tags: cats, toilet-training

I don't think she likes the smell of my clean bedding and is marking her territory,does anyone have any suggestions to stop this

Comment: I think I've seen this question before, but I can't find it, also; try to include as many details in your question. It makes it easier for those who want to answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

Siamese cats can be very conscious of their territory.  Mine became very visibly upset when we removed a poster from the wall.  They may also go in inappropriate places if they don't like the conditions of their litter box, or if they're upset by something, such as a break in their normal routine.

Especially if it persists, take the cat to the vet, to make sure it's not due to an underlying medical issue.  Once medical problems have been ruled out, it's a matter of trying stuff and seeing what works.  Here's a number of things to try:

1. Pick a litterbox habit and stick to it.  Make sure to that you figure out one location, type of litter, etc, that seems to work for her, and then keep it consistent.
2. Be sure you keep the box very clean.  Make sure to clean it at least once a day.  You may also try additional boxes, so the cat has other options besides the bed.
3. Make sure to clean the soiled bedding thoroughly, with cleaners designed to break up the smell.  This should help discourage repeat incidents.
4. Keep the cat out of your room.  You may be able to reintroduce the cat back into your room eventually, but for the time being, making her spots inaccessible may help break the habit, and make her go back to using the box.
5. Consider if there have been any other changes that may be stressing the cat, and see if you can mitigate.

Comment: Also, if this was *new* bedding (i.e. fresh out of the package), it may have a subtle chemical smell that smells a bit like urine to your cat. Your cat may think another cat has been there, and feel obliged to mark her territory. Washing all new bedding before use can help.